# RabbitMQ Pub/Sub - Subscriber is not able to receive message

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using sample code to implement Publish/Subscribe using "fanout" exchange type. But as in below code subscriber is not displaying 'Hello Word' message which is published.

**Publisher.cs**

```
 var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: "fanout");

            var message = GetMessage(args);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "logs",
                                 routingKey: "",
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetMessage(string[] args)
    {
        return ((args.Length > 0)
               ? string.Join(" ", args)
               : "info: Hello World!");
    }
```

**Subscriber.cs**

```
 var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: "fanout");

            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
            channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                              exchange: "logs",
                              routingKey: "");

            Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for logs.");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                                 noAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

**Code Ref:** https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html

Comment: What errors do you get? Is this exactly the same code as on the link you provided?

Comment: @cantSleepNow : No i am not getting any error, i have just created two console application one for publisher and another for subscriber.so first i am executing first publisher application and then executing subscriber but no response is coming in my console.

Comment: what about if you try vice versa, first subscriber than publisher?

Comment: @cantSleepNow : Working --- If i am executing subscriber console first and publishing later then it is working. does it means subscriber needs to be connected ???

Comment: I'm writing an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out it actually works, you just need to start the subscriber first. Why? The answer is also on the link you provided. I'll quote one part here:

> But that's not the case for our logger. We want to hear about all log
>   messages, not just a subset of them. We're also interested only in
>   **currently flowing messages not in the old ones**. To solve that we need
>   two things.
>
> Firstly, whenever we connect to Rabbit **we need a fresh, empty queue**.
>   To do this we could create a queue with a random name, or, even better
>   - let the server choose a random queue name for us.
>
> Secondly, once we disconnect the consumer the queue should be
>   automatically deleted.

This basically means that the queue is created only when you start the subscriber, and only at that point, the exchange has a queue to actually put the message in. Since you fist start the publisher, there is no queue for the message to end up in.